# AttributeError: 'Class Name' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, tkinter

So, I'm making a hangman game in python for my final in my programming class. I thought this last part (making the body appear depending on number of wrong guesses) would be easy. But so far, it's been very difficult and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Hangman(Frame, Words,):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    Words.__init__(self)


    self.parent = parent
    self.canvas = Canvas()
    self.hangedman()
    self.gallows()
    self.guessed()
    self.answer()
    self.keyBoard()

    self.wrong = IntVar()
    self.wrong.trace('w', self.hangedman)
    self.wrong.set(0)



def hangedman(self, *args):


    self.parent.title("Hangman")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    if (self.wrong.get() == 1):
        head = self.canvas.create_oval(130,130,190,190, fill="tan")

    else:
```

I'm new to inheritence and tkinter, so it may just be a silly mistake, but when I try to play the the game, I get this error.

```
File "C:\Users\Young\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\Hangman\classHangman.py", line 33, in hangedman
if (self.wrong.get() == 1):
AttributeError: 'Hangman' object has no attribute 'wrong'
```

I've tried moving it around, using with and without the 'self', I'm not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: You calling `self.hangedman()` before initializing `self.wrong`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something silly like that. Thanks again. :)